# OpenCV Sobel kernel aperture size 7 or 31

Tags: opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, sobel

The OpenCV documentation states that the maximum kernel size for the Sobel function is 7:

```
ksize:  size of the extended Sobel kernel; it must be 1, 3, 5, or 7.
```

Here's the link to the documentation:

https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gacea54f142e81b6758cb6f375ce782c8d

However, when coding I'm able to use a ksize up to 31 (over 31 gives an error). For example, I can execute the following:

```
cv2.Sobel(src=image, ddepth=-1, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=31)
```

Why does the documentation say up to 7, when it is allowed up to 31?

Comment: Must be a typo? [Source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.0.0-beta/modules/imgproc/src/deriv.cpp#L104) states that it must be odd & not larger than 31

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the kernel is padded with zeroes after the size exceeds 7x7.